# Java: Print variable values like Swift println()

Tags: java, android, variables, printing, android-studio

How do you print these variables below in Android Studio:

```
    globalVariable.setName("Android Example context variable");
    globalVariable.setEmail("xxxxxx@aaaa.com");
```

Debug Stream primarily, but TextView if possible.

Under public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) I am trying:

```
    final GlobalClass globalVariable = (GlobalClass) getApplicationContext();
    globalVariable.setName("Android Example context variable");
    globalVariable.setEmail("xxxxxx@aaaa.com");
    Log.d("your_tag", "Name: " + globalVariable.getName());
    Log.d("your_tag", "Email: " + globalVariable.getEmail());
```

But it says unfortunately application stopped working.

Comment: Uh, set a textview to contain `globalVariable.getName()`? Or do you mean print to a debug stream?

Comment: Both ideally, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you click "6: Android" button near "4: Run" button in the bottom status bar. It will show `Logcat` console.

You can print to this log in your code by using below code

```
Log.d("your_tag", "printed_message");
```

So in your case, that would be

```
Log.d("your_tag", "Name: " + globalVariable.getName());
Log.d("your_tag", "Email: " + globalVariable.getEmail());
```

For setting a TextView with these string variables, do like below

```
//Do this in onCreate, after setContentLayout();
TextView yourTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourViewId);
yourTextView.setText(globalVariable.getName());
```

Comment: Place that under public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) ??